# fullCalendar wont load title on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, fullcalendar

I have a fullCalendar on my site which should load the month when the page is loaded up, but for some reason the month's title wont load until a month selection button is pressed.

I'm probably overlooking something simple, could anyone have a look at tell me where I'm going wrong.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".calendar").fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    editable: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    timezone: 'local',
    header: {
      left: "",
      center: "prev, title, next",
      right: ""
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    viewDisplay: function(view) {

    },
    columnFormat: {
      month: 'dddd',
      week: 'dddd D/M',
      day: 'dddd D/M'
    },
    allDayDefault: false,
    eventSources: [

      // your event source
      {

        url: 'https://www.burtonstreetcrm.co.uk/scripts/booking_session_calendar.php', // use the `url` property
        textColor: 'white' // an option!
      }
      // any other sources...
    ],

    eventOrder: "lookup_building",
    // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

      // end hide dates //

      if (event.allDay === 'true') {
        event.allDay = true;
      } else {
        event.allDay = false;
      }



    },

    eventClick: function(event) {
      if (event.id) {}

    },
    selectable: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar" class="calendar"></div>
```

Comment: I can't understand how your title relates to the question in any way?

Comment: Oh sorry, it was a a title from a previous issue. I'll change it now. Thanks

Comment: Ok thanks. I made your snippet runnable. Obviously the event feed won't work from here due to security restrictions,  but in relation to your question, I can see the month name without having to click anything. I'm not clear what your actual issue is...perhaps you can modify the snippet until it reproduces your problem for us to see? You also seem to have a problem with format of your dates in the columns - check that you've used valid code. The "columnFormat" option is deprecated, and anyway it's not used the way you've used it...are you using an older version of fullCalendar, perhaps?

Comment: There's also no such thing as a "viewDisplay" callback - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc . Not sure where you got the idea for that from?

Comment: http://nikhil.nyuidevelopers.in.net/FullCalender/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `columnFormat: {
      month: 'dddd',
      week: 'dddd D/M',
      day: 'dddd D/M'
    },`

As per document it accepts string value not Array
so 
`columnFormat:'dddd'` will give you expected output

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".calendar").fullCalendar({
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    editable: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    timezone: 'local',
    header: {
       left: 'prev,next today',
       center: 'title',
       right: 'year,month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    viewDisplay: function(view) {

    },
    columnFormat:'dddd',
    allDayDefault: false,
    eventSources: [

      // your event source
      {

        url: 'https://www.burtonstreetcrm.co.uk/scripts/booking_session_calendar.php', // use the `url` property
        textColor: 'white' // an option!
      }
      // any other sources...
    ],

    eventOrder: "lookup_building",
    // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {

      // end hide dates //

      if (event.allDay === 'true') {
        event.allDay = true;
      } else {
        event.allDay = false;
      }



    },

    eventClick: function(event) {
      if (event.id) {}

    },
    selectable: true,
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
<div id="calendar" class="calendar"></div>
```